# Stylelint shows "Unexpected URL scheme "data" if I use SVGs as background in my CSS

Tags: stylelint

I'm using some SVG images in the CSS file like this:

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23637581' d='M101.3 141.6v228.9h309.5V141.6H101.3zm274.4 26.2L256 259.3l-119.6-91.5h239.3zm-248.1 26.3l64.1 49.1-64.1 64.1V194.1zm.2 150.1l84.9-84.9 43.2 33.1 43-32.9 84.7 84.7H127.8zm256.6-36.4L320 243.4l64.4-49.3v113.7z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

It works. However Stylelint is complaining with this error:

```
Unexpected URL scheme "data:"   function-url-scheme-disallowed-list
```

Does anyone know how to fix the URL to get rid of the stylelint error?

Comment: I ran into that before. I changed the url encoding. IE would complain but most browsers wouldn't care. The format has to be perfect, so Google an example that works and emulate it.

Comment: It's kind of contradict that you want to have "style-linted" your code and you use inline svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stylelint is only complaining about the `data` scheme because it's been configured to do that via the [function-url-scheme-disallowed-list rule](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/function-url-scheme-disallowed-list/). There's nothing wrong with the URL, and disallowing the `data` scheme is purely a preference.

Neither of the [official](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-recommended) [configs](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard) turn this rule on. Either you or the author of the 3rd party config you're extending has turned it on and configured it to disallow the `data` scheme.

You'll either need to:

- find out why that is, and use whatever alternative is suggested
- turn the rule off or configure it allow the `data` scheme